# MVC app inside WebForm app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net website built in .net 3.5. When clicking on one of the aspx page, I want to open an MVC appliation inside that page. MVC app is developed by another company. What is the best way of doing that?

Scott Hanselman's [Article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) doesn't include this scenario I guess.

Comment: Just do `Response.Redirect("[urlOfOtherWebSite]");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what kind of interaction you are expecting between your app and the externally developed app. If the UI isn't going to interact between them then an iframe is probably what you're looking for. If it is going to interact then you can interact between them using exposes apis or web services on both sides.