# Webforms APP Inside ASP.NET MVC 4 in IIS Folder Structure - Not in the project itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms

My Scenario:

I have this legacy application written in .NET WebForms

Now we have developed a new application in ASP.NET MVC 4 w/ .NET 4.5.

I need to organize it in a folder structure as follows:

**/** --> Here the NEW

**/TravelPlan** --> Here the Legacy

So I came up with deploying the NEW one on the Root folder of IIS and deploying the legacy on the TravelPlan folder.

After both deployments, I can access with success the root folder application, BUT, when I type **/travelplan/** I get an error.

[image: error that happens when accessing the application from the MVC root]

I was considering at first this as a routing problem. Since the path exists, ASP.NET MVC recognizes the folder, and uses it's own web.config to run the application.

So, as an attempt to fix that I tried to add this in RouteConfig.cs of the root app

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("TravelPlan/{*path}");
routes.Ignore("TravelPlan");
```

With no success.

As you can see on the image it's a dll missing, but if I remove the root application, the TravelPlan app works as expected. That's why I figured that the root app is messing the /TravelPlan/ app.

Any ideas?

I've also checked both links below - they do not cover my question:

[MVC app inside WebForm app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10733662/mvc-app-inside-webform-app)

[Asp.net WebForms app that runs MVC in a subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378666/asp-net-webforms-app-that-runs-mvc-in-a-subfolder)

Comment: Have you set /travelplan/ as an application in your IIS Manager? Because otherwise, it will not be considered an application but rather a subdirectory of your new MVC application.